# I can not find hid.h file in arduino

Tags: arduino, barcode-scanner, hid

I have a this error in arduino:

> fatal error: hid.h: No such file or directory

How can I find or download hid.h file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install this library in library folder. The lib folder is inside arduino's folder or in your documents.
https://github.com/arduino-libraries/USBHost

Comment: you're welcome! =) please, mark this answer as the right one.